# How to make unecesary text Messenger bot nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-messenger-bot

So, I build a **messenger bot using node js**. How can I make:

1. Whenever user send a random text (except the right command) the Bot will reply "Sorry I cant recognize that command"..
2. How to make bot storing the Text from user and will confirm later ? Example : 
   USER : Hello.
   BOT : What Else ?
   USER : World.
   BOT : What Else ?
   USER : done.
   BOT : I understood,
   BOT : 1. Hello
   BOT : 2. World
   BOT : Is that correct ?

Here is my current scripts for no. 1 :

```
function replyByText(sender, text, payload) {
let kata = text.toLowerCase()
let date = new Date()
let current_hour = date.getHours()
if (S(kata).contains('produk') || S(kata).contains('produknya') || S(kata).contains('product')) {
    sendOpeningProduct(sender, "Wait Sec..")
}

if (S(kata).contains('layanan')|| S(kata).contains('services')|| S(kata).contains('diagnose')){
    // sendOpeningServices(sender, 'Wait sec..' )
    sendPlainMessage(sender, 'Hi, what concern you most about your health? Please describe your symptoms..' )
}

if (S(kata).contains('health symptoms')){
    sendPlainMessage(sender, 'Tell me What You Feel..' )
}

if (S(kata).contains('im feeling sick') || S(kata).contains('im feeling unwell') || S(kata).contains('im feeling dizzy') || S(kata).contains('dizzy') || S(kata).contains('sick')){
    sendPlainMessage(sender, 'How old are you ?' )
}

if (S(kata).contains('3') || S(kata).contains('4') || S(kata).contains('5') || S(kata).contains('6') || S(kata).contains('7') || S(kata).contains('8') || S(kata).contains('9')){
    sendPlainMessage(sender, 'I see...' )
    sendOpeningProductKids(sender, "Just try our products")
}}
```

Any help will appreciate..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to No 1:

```
function replyByText(sender, text, payload) {
    let kata = text.toLowerCase()
    let date = new Date()
    let current_hour = date.getHours()

    if (S(kata).contains('produk') || S(kata).contains('produknya') || S(kata).contains('product')) {
        sendOpeningProduct(sender, "Wait Sec..")
    }

    else if (S(kata).contains('layanan')|| S(kata).contains('services')|| S(kata).contains('diagnose')){
        // sendOpeningServices(sender, 'Wait sec..' )
        sendPlainMessage(sender, 'Hi, what concern you most about your health? Please describe your symptoms..' )
    }

    else if (S(kata).contains('health symptoms')){
        sendPlainMessage(sender, 'Tell me What You Feel..' )
    }

    else if (S(kata).contains('im feeling sick') || S(kata).contains('im feeling unwell') || S(kata).contains('im feeling dizzy') || S(kata).contains('dizzy') || S(kata).contains('sick')){
        sendPlainMessage(sender, 'How old are you ?' )
    }

    else if (S(kata).contains('3') || S(kata).contains('4') || S(kata).contains('5') || S(kata).contains('6') || S(kata).contains('7') || S(kata).contains('8') || S(kata).contains('9')){
        sendPlainMessage(sender, 'I see...' )
        sendOpeningProductKids(sender, "Just try our products")
    }
    else{
        sendPlainMessage(sender, 'Sorry I cant recognize that command' )
    }

}
```

Solution to No 2:

You will have to save state between each call to your webhook. follow these steps.

There are several ways to solve this problem. You may solve this problem this way. Save state by updating a covesation model/object on each webhook call. Use the user's unique psid got from facebook api as a primary key or as part of a composite key for the model/object

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using BootBot (https://github.com/Charca/bootbot), a nodejs framework that makes Messenger bot development relatively easy. It has features to easily check user's input and save the context of a conversation.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, A switch/ case statement would be ideal. In case any cases are not met, the default action would be "Sorry, I can't recognize that command".